Why does Spring MVC repeatedly retrieve the HandlerExecutionChain for each request?
Creating a new HandlerExecutionChain on each request results in repeated execution of regular expression matching logic, cause excessive memory allocation.
Spring boot web version: 2.7.0
 protected HandlerExecutionChain getHandlerExecutionChain(Object handler, HttpServletRequest request) {
        HandlerExecutionChain chain = handler instanceof HandlerExecutionChain ? (HandlerExecutionChain)handler : new HandlerExecutionChain(handler);
        Iterator var4 = this.adaptedInterceptors.iterator();

        while(var4.hasNext()) {
            HandlerInterceptor interceptor = (HandlerInterceptor)var4.next();
            if (interceptor instanceof MappedInterceptor) {
                MappedInterceptor mappedInterceptor = (MappedInterceptor)interceptor;
                if (mappedInterceptor.matches(request)) {
                    chain.addInterceptor(mappedInterceptor.getInterceptor());
                }
            } else {
                chain.addInterceptor(interceptor);
            }
        }

        return chain;
    }

public boolean match(Object path, boolean isPathContainer, PathMatcher pathMatcher) {
            if (isPathContainer) {
                PathContainer pathContainer = (PathContainer)path;
                if (this.pathPattern != null) {
                    return this.pathPattern.matches(pathContainer);
                }

                String lookupPath = pathContainer.value();
                path = UrlPathHelper.defaultInstance.removeSemicolonContent(lookupPath);
            }

            return pathMatcher.match(this.patternString, (String)path);
        }

The following is a flame graph of memory allocation.
Problem flame graph

Because it needs to know what interceptors apply to which requests. The requests that come in aren't limited to certain URLs/paths etc. so it needs to determine each time.
